# Why Spark kills the driver process in case of an exception?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm a new user of Spark Streaming and Spark. During my tests, I have noticed that a single error in the stream makes the entire streaming application failed.

To be more clear, let me explain with an example. Suppose that the submitted application consumes an integer stream like `15, 10, 21, 12, ...`. But, this stream may carry some non-integer strings (e.g. `15, 10, 21, 12, foo, 32, ...`) by mistake. If my code has a bug and assumes all data items are integers, then it will throw an exception while processing `foo` string in the stream.

In such a case, Spark engine retries the task 3 times by default (you can check [config documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/configuration.html#scheduling) for `spark.task.maxFailures` parameter). Then, after all unsuccessful attempts it aborts the driver process and hence the executors.

I'm not sure this is the correct behaviour. Instead, I thought that the current task (i.e. execution of a partial data) or the batch (i.e. bunch of data items read from the stream) would be discarded. So, the driver would process the remaining stream.

Any idea why Spark behaves like that? Are there any configurations to force the engine to ignore the failures and keep going?

By the way, I'm using Spark in standalone mode. Can YARN or Mesos help for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd read it as a string column and handle the incorrect data manually.

Answer (score 2):

If Spark failed silently, how would you ever know that something had gone wrong? (YARN or Mesos won't help with this.)

Like Reactormonk suggests, you should specify how you want failures to be handled as part of the function you're passing to Spark. If you just want to discard the mistaken rows and you're using Scala, you might want to do something like the following:

```
val strRDD = sc.parallelize(Array("15", "10", "21", "12", "foo", "32"),1)
val intRDD = strRDD.flatMap(x => try{Some(x.toInt)} catch {case e: Exception => None})
intRDD.collect()
```

This will return `Array[Int] = Array(15, 10, 21, 12, 32)`.

Comment: Ok with manual handling but I need to learn whether Spark has a built-in support for silently skipping erroneous executions. It may notify me about failed tasks via a listener API and I can say ignore this and go on.